# Adding values with callback in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After generating a scaffold like String Decimal{8,2} String
which works correctly I want to add all the decimals and do some other calculations with them before showing the results on the same page (root view).

I guess I have to use active record callbacks to invoke the calculations every time an entry is made, edited or deleted.

Can somebody show me the right direction for solving this?
I guess I have to put the callback function in my provisions_controller.rb, right? How should that look correctly?

Comment: are these calculations saved in the database? like for example doing some additions and putting the result in a field called `sum` ?

Comment: maybe I'll do so later on. For now as I am totally new to Rails I would be proud to display them on the root view.

Comment: I'm asking to understand if you want to write these calculations or to read them? you could just make them methods so that you only calculate them whenever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your `provisions_controller` will do

```
#with ActionController Filter method before_filter
before_filter :do_calculations, :only => [:create, :edit, :delete]

private

def do_calculations
#do your stuff
end
```

Comment: this looks promising... I'm just too stupid to make the result show up on the view.... <%= @results.inspect  %> ???

Comment: That does not seem to work. The result that the view is showing is nil